# Trying to get slider to work properly

Tags: wordpress, plugins, slideshow, cyclone

I am using Cyclone Slider 2 on the following page: http://alexistmyers.com/test/ I have 2 slides in this slider, but it's only showing one, basically it's not cycling as it should. I have the settings set to automatically cycle through and in the admin section of the plugin it shows as cycling through, accept it won't do so on the actual page.

The weird part about this is, I used this exact same slider in another website I just created and it works perfectly. You can see it in action here: http://www.24hrbookkeeper.com/

I went to the forum for this plugin and they mentioned to go to Tools -> Web Developer -> Error Console in Firefox (I'm using Firefox to make these changes). I did that, but I did not see "Error Console", instead I see "Web Console" so I clicked on that, and this is what I see...

[20:54:27.874] "[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector"

This must mean something's wrong. Any ideas what this means and how to get this slider to work correctly on the first site I mentioned above? Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your code for the first page?

Comment: Hi, there is no code to get this slider to show up. I'm using the Cyclone Slider 2 plugin. It only gives short code to place into the page to get the slider to show up. Here it is: [cycloneslider id="portfolio"]

Comment: Do you have plugins activated in the first site that are not in the second one?

Comment: Yes, definitely. You think that's the issue?

Comment: Its probably the most common issue with plugins so its worth testing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a conflict with another plugin but here are three things you can try:

1. Deactivate all plugins and reactivate them one by one.
2. Check that the plugin was properly installed and activated.
3. Check the link to the image in your media library and test with another image.